# How do I add a material on top of others?

Tags: materials, node-editor

I've got two materials on a mesh. How do I add a noise/musgrave/any texture on top of both?

*(I tried to do this individually on each, but I got some ugly seams.)*

Comment: Hello :). Do you mean a *seamless* Musgrave texture over multiple materials? Or combining two different materials?

Comment: @JachymMichal A seamless texture over multiple materials.